# Expected primary expression before ")"

Tags: c++

In the 8th line below, I get a compiler error that says:

> Expected primary expression before token ")"

What does it mean, and what is the mistake? I'm new to this, so please help!

```
float a,b,c;
printf("side1=");
scanf("%f",&a);
printf("side2=");
scanf("%f",&b);
printf("side3=");
scanf("%f",&c);
((a||b||c||)!=0&&(a+b)>c&&(b+c)>a&&(a+c)>b)?printf("Triangle"):printf("NOT a TRIANGLE");
getch();
```

Comment: It means the parser found a `)` where it can't appear. The error message also gives the exact location of the offending token.

Comment: `(..c||)`, you probably want to remote `||` after `c`

Comment: While true you can use the ternary operator, it's better in this particular case to use an `if-else` instruction for better readability.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: `((a||b||c||)!=0&&(a+b)>c&&(b+c)>a&&(a+c)>b)?printf("Triangle"):printf("NOT a TRIANGLE");` -- I guess this is your entry to the obfuscated `C` contest.

Comment: @Noshwin If you are stuck with errors in complex code lines try to reduce complexity. E.g. move the large expression into a dedicated line  (bool is_triangle = ((a||...) and use this in the ternary operator (?:)

Comment: use` ( (a !=0) && (b !=0) && (c !=0)  )` instead of `a||b||c||)!=0`

Answer (score -1):

If you are checking for a OR b OR c then it should be `a||b||c` not `a||b||c||`.